# How to import from a csv file already written as a nested tuple?

Tags: python, csv, import, nested, tuples

I have a file called 'test.csv'. You can see the first three lines in the attached [test.csv.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bivYM.jpg).

```
'ID','NO_QUESTION','NO_RESPONSE','VALUE','MEMORY','AVAILABILITY','CLICK_EFFET'
'34','01','01','1','1','0',('q01a01vato1dito0','q01a02vato0dito1')
'35','01','02','0','0','1',('q01a01vato0dito1','q01a02vato1dito0')
```

First line is the header. Other lines have the first six positions as Strings, but the seventh position as a Tuple of N Strings. The seventh position has parenthesis. Sometimes N==0 so the seventh position is empty.

I want to import this as a nested tuple into my program, and call it 'data'. The .py file of my program is in the same directory as 'test.csv'. I want:

len(data) == number of lines of test.csv

len(data[x]) == 7 for the seven positions of any x

len(data[x][6]) == number of strings within the seventh position of line x

What is the pythonic way of doing this ? Thanks

Comment: Consider pasting the sample CSV as text in the question so that we can copy and play with it.

Comment: Good idea. Just done it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid CSV format (if it were, the entire tuple would be escaped and presented as a single column of the CSV) so this solution has its risks. Assuming that the parens are simply demarking the variable columns that the end of the the line (and assuming parens aren't valid in the other fields), you could simply strip them out. Its valid to have a variable column count in a CSV so the python parser won't have a problem with them.

Once you have parsed a given line into a row using `csv.reader`, you can simply use list slicing to select the parts you want to keep.

This should keep the first 6 cells and a count of the remainders.

```
import csv
import re

data = []
strip_paren = re.compile(r'\(\)')

with open('test.csv', newline='') as fp:
    # skip header
    next(fp)
    # strip parens so lines will parse as csv
    for row in csv.reader((re.sub(r'\(\)', '', line) for line in fp),
        quotechar="'"):
        # split row for nested data info
        data.append(row[:6] + [len(row[6:])])

print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code will be useful to extract the number of 'CLICK_EFFET' for each row. But I made the text.csv file to simplify the problem of importing nested tuples here. In my real program, I intend to have many positions with a N number of strings. For example if want to add a 'CLICK_CONDITION' variable there is going to be another list of many conditions. So extracting the first fixed positions is not going to help... I want to use a dictionnary to fix the list of CLCK_CONDITION and CLICK_EFFET for each QUESTION / RESPONSE combination, but I am going to face the same nesteddata problem.

Comment: I'm a bit late getting back.... It sounds like you control the encoding side of this file also. Consider using an encoding that handles tuples natively such as JSON. Since this text format isn't straight CSV, it may be best to try something else.